# Warning while compiling libraries with both C and C++ files

Tags: c++, c, c++11, codeblocks, c99

I am working on the project which contains both C++ files and C files. In Code::Blocks, I have selected the following checkbox `-std=c++11` in project build options.

[image]

Then get the following warning.

```
||warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]|
```

If I also check the checkbox of `-std=c99`,

[image]

I will get an additional warning as the following.

```
||warning: command line option ‘-std=c99’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]|
```

Is there a way to work around this? Can I set the `-std=c++11` flag for only the `C++` files and `-std=c99` for the C files?

Comment: Is there anything that is preventing you from simply compiling all the C files as C++ files?

Comment: No, there is not. I am just a bit annoyed by those warnings and wondering whether there is a way to get rid of them.

Comment: Yes, compile everything as C++ code and do not set the `-std=c99` flag.

Comment: But in this case I will get warnings for compiling `.c` files with `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, the problem is, I will get the warning with only `-std=c++11`. The warning is `||warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C`

Comment: All that says is that you are still compiling it as C code. Compile it as C++ code. http://industriousone.com/topic/how-specify-projectfile-compiled-c-code-or-c-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are having this problem because you have enabled the `-std=c++11`
option in the **Global compiler settings** for GCC. I know you say you have enabled it
in "project build options", but enabling it in global compiler options is what causes
this behaviour.

It a bug in C::B that this global option is described as:

> Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard

when in fact it will be applied to both `g++` and `gcc`.

However you are probably ill-advised to set a C++ language standard option
in the *global* compiler options, even if it would only apply to `g++`. That
way, you won't ever be able to build any C++ projects that conform to
an earlier standard than C++11 but not C++11.

You should go back to **Global compiler settings**, click **Reset defaults** and
OK out. Then set the `-std=c++11` compiler option (and any other non-default
options that you want) at the *project* level:

Right-click on your project in the workspace tree-view and open **Build options**.
Ensure the **Selected compiler** is **GNU GCC Compiler** and select the
**Compiler settings** -> **Compiler flags** tab. There you will see the
same list of checkboxes for compiler options that you saw in **Global compiler settings**.
Enable the `-std=c++11` option and OK out.

Now, any `.c` files in your project will automatically be compiled with `gcc`,
without any `g++`-specific flags, and `.cpp` files will automatically be
compiled with `g++`, with `-std=c++11` and any other `g++` options you have
chosen.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in a older version of Code::blocks that I was using. I updated it and everything is fine now. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this:

[Using Global Compiler Variables](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-1020003.7)

It describes different compiler variables, and build options.  It is most likely there that you will need to either make a change or find out what variables are used specifically for each C and C++ targets that are compiled.